# ModalView rotation with a thick border (like iBooks app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiviewcontroller

```
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Is there any way to make it flipping with a thick border/side? (like iBooks app, when you're switching between books view and the books store)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code or API Apple used for this transition is not publicly available, so you would need to implement your own custom OpenGL transition.  Lucky for you, someone else had the same idea and implemented a helper class that includes a thick-border flip transition: [EPGLTransitionView](http://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView).  If this is not to your liking, check out this [SO thread on custom view transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309880/custom-view-transition-in-opengl-es).

Answer (score 1):

EPGLTransitionView uses OpenGL. Try this project instead, fully done in CoreAnimation:

https://github.com/devindoty/iBooks-Flip-Animation